# Scrolling images against the scroll origination - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am wondering what is the name of the effect when the images scroll against the page scroll orientation giving a 2D feel to the page.

Refer to [Google Nexus](http://www.google.co.uk/nexus/7) website and scroll down, can you notice the effect?

What is it called? is it JavaScript? CSS3? Any links to tutorials?

Comment: It's referred to as a parallax effect: google that term and you'll find copious examples. It's a combination of CSS and JavaScript. [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) is a decent implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey its a paralax effect you can achive it with this javascript plugin https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr its very easy to use to if you need some example just let me know.

Comment: Is there a very simple way to do it? rather using a PLugin please?

Comment: I advise you to use that plugin it is very straight foward, but you can check this tutorials http://wedesignpixel.com/best-jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials/ the have here prety good examples the one i found the simplier is: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html you need to have you background images bigger thant the container in order to "scroll/move" them upwards.

Comment: If you need any more help please let me know.

Comment: Please take a look here: http://loaidesign.co.uk/php/projects.php?project=1 that is my website that I am working on, the picutre on the very top is what I want add the effect too, so they are not two images or more, it's only one image and I want to give it a nice feeling effect when you scroll down to the project :/ any ideas mate?

Comment: first what i would do is separate the bubbles background from the text, and in order to get the desired effect you background needs to be bigger than the container that way you can slowly scroll it check this example http://source.tutsplus.com/webdesign/tutorials/005_parallax/demo/index.html it uses the plugin i talked about.